# Cross compiling kernel, using Makefile. How to suppress -Wunused-but-set-variable warning

Tags: gcc, compilation, makefile

I'm trying to Cross compile a kernel for Android using Ubuntu.

After successfully setting up the menuconfig, and compiling with the following option:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE="arm-bravo-" -i -j10
```

It starts building, but then terminates with a lot of these errors:

```
error: variable '*something*' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Now I understand that this can be fixed by running gcc with `--disable-werror` option. Probem is that this is a huge project (kernel) and I am not well versed enough with make and Makefile, to know where I have to set this value. Kindly help me understand and fix this problem.

Answer (score 20):

After weeks, I'm now in a position to answer my own question..

Look for `KBUILD_CFLAGS` in the main Makefile, and add the following to suppress warnings as errors:

```
KBUILD_CFLAGS += -w
// if all errors are to be suppressed

KBUILD_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable
// if that specific error is to be suppressed.
```